# how to get 1 row value from (onclick) selected row datatables vue js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-data-tables

hello i didnt have any example to try this method.. 
can any one give me some little example for take 1 row value from datatable (onclick) selected row on vue js.

this is my template table

```
<template>
<div class="table-responsive">
 <datatable title="" :rows="tableData" :columns="columndata" :options="options"></datatable>
</div>
</template>
```

and this is my javascript

```
export default { 
   data(){
     return {
       columns: ['id', 'name', 'age'],
      tableData: [
          { id: 1, name: "John", age: "20" },
          { id: 2, name: "Jane", age: "24" },
          { id: 3, name: "Susan", age: "16" },
          { id: 4, name: "Chris", age: "55" },
          { id: 5, name: "Dan", age: "40" }
      ],
      options: {
          // see the options API
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What package do you use as datatable?

Comment: @ThomasKleßen bootstrap-vue and vue-tables-2